# "ag-grid update with gridOptions"

Tags: angular

I have a question. After ag-grid created, can I still update gridOptions? For example, at beginning pagenation is not enabled. After rows increase, then it is enabled. Can we do this and how?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Hi @Junior Javier Escoto and welcome to SO, Can you please provide some examples of what you tried and what is not working

Comment: @TamirKlein a simple example, I have the following structure, `this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{ enableFilter: true};` and later with a button I want to change the filter property to false, for that I need to update the gridOptions object